# twitter bootstrap tooltips over buttons inside table not displaying correctly

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to show buttons with tooltips inside a table, using twitter bootstrap.

The problem is that the tooltips inserts additional space between buttons, and the last button doesn't have the rounded corners anymore. How can this be fixed?

Another problem is that if the button is opening a modal dialog, upon closing it the button gets the focus and the tooltip is shown again.

The buttons are created by ajax requests, so here's how I initialize the tooltips:

```
$('body').tooltip({
selector: '[rel=tooltip]:not(.disabled)',
live: true,
container: 'body'
```

});

Here is the jsfiddle for it: http://jsfiddle.net/danut007ro/y8vNr/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is this:

```
.btn-group>.btn+.btn {
margin-left: -1px;
}
```

There is a border and your using -1 margin to hide oen side to make it look a single border line. If you want to stop jumping, then remove that rule, but then you'll see two border lines between buttons.

A real fix would be to use this(in addition of removing the above rule):

```
.btn {
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
    }
.btn:last-child {
    border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I updated the fiddle to include your answer. But still, there is no border on the last button. Any ideas on the modal problem? (press the delete button and you'll see what I mean).

Thanks.

Comment: For the tooltip problem I ended up using answer from https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/5704#issuecomment-14364066. This still looks like a live tooltip issue, because initializing the tooltip not in live mode by using
`$('[rel=tooltip]').tooltip({
    container: 'body'
});`
and removing extra css, it displays ok

Answer (score 0):

Set data-container="body" attribute on the button elements which appends the tool-tip element on the body. It rectifies the jerk as well as the border-radius issue on last button.