# Bootstrap button group malfunction when they have tooltips

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a single group button with a tooltip enabled for each button.
On hover in the last button of the group, the tooltip causes misalignment and the border of the button is no longer rounded. I know that the  tooltip style is overriding the button style but I cannot find where is.

DEMO: [Bootply](http://bootply.com/72509)

**UPDATE:**

Fixed by changing the `<a>` element with a `<button>` elemnt and then using a custom style

Button:

```
<button class="btn btn-small btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" title="Unlink" data-target="#@item.WOWorkPermitID"><i class="icon-resize-full icon-white"></i></button>
```

CSS:

```
.btn-group > .btn:last-of-type {
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-top-right-radius: 4px;
    border-top-right-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
}
```

DEMO --> [Bootply](http://bootply.com/72524)

Related post --> [twitter bootstrap tooltips over buttons inside table not displaying correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16630442/twitter-bootstrap-tooltips-over-buttons-inside-table-not-displaying-correctly?rq=1)

Comment: this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18488413/bootstrap-tooltip-with-dropdown-in-button-group-seems-to-have-an-effect seems to be the best answer

Answer (score 1):

try

```
 $(".btn").tooltip({     
    'placement': 'top',
    container: 'body'  
 });
```

it worked to me :)

Comment: adding the `container` parameter worked for me. I didn't need to add any custom stylings

Answer (score 0):

The last item isn't a button, it's an anchor. Try changing it to a button like the first two items.

Comment: I think that is not the problem. The '<a>' item has a 'class="btn btn-small btn-danger"'. In addition, is working properly by removing the tooltip Javascript. Look at this DEMO using three buttons with tooltips --> http://bootply.com/72515

Comment: Yeah I saw that now, I've just tried stripping it down to the bare minimum and it's still happening, not sure if the tooltip control just doesn't play nicely with the button styling?

Comment: For sure!! That is! Althought the `<a>` element is acting as a button, the CSS is not applying the `.btn-group > .btn:last-of-type` style when it has a tooltip, so the border is not rounded. I have fixed it by changing the `<a>` element with a `<button>` and then using a custom style. See my updated post.

Comment: Ahh cool, well done. I've also just done a project using Bootstrap and I remember their being a few oddities like this.

Comment: Thanks @Damon :) Even though my question (and subsequent posted solution) shows effort, there remain people on this website giving downvotes with no meaning omg!