# bootstrap, tooltip with dropdown, in button group seems to have an effect

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

In bootstrap, tooltip with dropdown,  the hover data-toggle attached to one button in a button group seems to have an effect when I hover mouse on the button that is responsible for tool tip then it also adjust its position that does not look good. Please help me.

Here is my code:-

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">    
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen"/>
    <link href="css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen"/>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="btn-group">
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-small btn-inverse add1" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="" data-original-title="Add to Selected Contacts">Add</a>
      <a class="btn  btn-inverse dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
          <span class="caret"></span>
      </a>
 <a href="#" class="btn btn-small btn-inverse add1" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="" data-original-title="Add to Selected Contacts">Add</a>
 <a class="btn  btn-inverse dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
          <span class="caret"></span>
   </a>
 </div>                                            
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jQuery v1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
    // tooltip demo
    $('.add1').tooltip()
  </script>                               
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try adding the `container: 'body'` option. This will append the tooltip to the body instead of within the buttons container.

```
$('.add1').tooltip({
    container: 'body'
})
```

Answer (score 1):

No need for the javascript code.

Just add the below attribute on the anchor elements which toggles the tooltip.

```
data-container="body"
```

On your code it goes like,

```
<div class="btn-group">
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-small btn-inverse add1" data-toggle="tooltip" data-container="body" data-placement="bottom" title="" data-original-title="Add to Selected Contacts">Add</a>
      <a class="btn  btn-inverse dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
          <span class="caret"></span>
      </a>
 <a href="#" class="btn btn-small btn-inverse add1" data-toggle="tooltip" data-container="body" data-placement="bottom" title="" data-original-title="Add to Selected Contacts">Add</a>
 <a class="btn  btn-inverse dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
          <span class="caret"></span>
   </a>
 </div>
```